# HTTP XML data through SSH on port 8080

Tags: linux, web-services, http, ssh

I have deployed a web service which should receive XML data on port 8080. The other service is pushing this data from the remote host. 
But as for my server, it has only a local IP-address. I can access it only with ssh from outside. When I asked the administrator, he said that HTTP-data pushing should be done through ssh tunnel. 
The question is - how is it possbile to do? How can I configure the local server to receive XML data with HTTP through SSH? And what is the common way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this from sender :

```
ssh <ssh_username>@<yourserverip> -L 7070:localhost:8080 -N
```

Then, if you send XML data to "localhost:7070", data will be redirected to port 8080 of 'yourserverip'. If your server has a SSH daemon running, there is nothing to do on server side.

More information : http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html